# centering animation view in top center in relative layout

Tags: android

i have the shown below circle animation which will be animated by the class circle , it keeps animating in top left no matter what i do , gravity, center layout , nothing , please help i am really stuck here, here is my xml,
so the circle appears on right top of the screen , i want it to appear in center top of the screen after animation, thanks.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 

tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.mynetwork.zaidkhaled.animation_test.circle

    android:id="@+id/circle"

    android:layout_width="300dp"

    android:layout_height="300dp"

    />

<Button

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text=" animate"

    android:id="@+id/animate"

    android:textColor="#000000"

    android:background="#ffffff"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put these attributes to the circle widget:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:gravity="center"
```

And this to the button:

```
android:layout_below="@id/circle"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer man , but that didnt work still drawn on the top right :(

Comment: sorry imeant top left

Comment: i cant post picture here

Comment: can i send you apic on fb pls? so maybe u will sove it

Comment: Sure man, but I don't have a fb profile. May be use sites like http://share.pho.to/ or http://tinypic.com/ , and post the link here.